# Continuity of probability and finite additivity

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> In the context of probability measures we have introduced $\sigma$-continuity "from below" and "from above", respectively.
>
> i.) **$\sigma$-continuity from below**:
>
> Let be $B_{1} \subseteq B_{2} \subseteq B_{3} \subseteq \cdots$ an increasing sequences of subsets. Then it holds: $\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left(B_{n} \right) = P\left( \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{i}\right)$.
>
> ii.) **$\sigma$-continuity from above**:
>
> Let be $B_1\supseteq B_{2} \supseteq B_{3} \supseteq \cdots$ a decreasing sequence of subsets. Then it holds: $ \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(B_{n}\right)= P\left( \cap_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i}\right)$.

My question is:

If $P$ is just a function, does it have to be finitely additive to show that i.) and ii.) are equivalent? (If i.) holds then it implies ii.) and vice versa)

I would say no, because by taking the complement one can deduce the other statement and in none of the steps I need finite additivity.

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is that if $P$ is $\sigma$-continuous from below at a set $B$, then what you can prove by taking the complements is that $P$ is also $\sigma$-continuous from above at the complement of $B$, but not at $B$ itself.

I.e., Your proof works to show that

($\forall B, P$ is $\sigma$-continuous from below at $B$) $\iff$ ($\forall B, P$ is $\sigma$-continuous from above at $B$).

But it does not show

$\forall B$, ($P$ is $\sigma$-continuous from below at $B \iff P$ is $\sigma$-continuous from above at $B$).

Comment: Maybe it needs some clarification: Let be $(B_n)_n$ a monot. decr. sequence with the limit $B:=\cap^{\infty}_{n=1}B_n$. Let's assume i.) holds. Then $(B_n^c)_n$ is a monot. incr. sequence with the limit $B^c:=\cup^{\infty}_{n=1} B_n^c$, where the script $c$ denotes the complement. From this we can deduce:$$\lim_{n\to \infty}P(B_n^c)=P(\cup^{\infty}_{n=1}B_n^c)=P((\cap^{\infty}_{n=1}B_n)^c)=1-P(\cap^{\infty}_{n=1}B_n).$$Hence,$$1-P(\cap^{\infty}_{n=1} B_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty} P(B_n^c)\Rightarrow P(\cap^{\infty}_{n=1}B_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}P(B_n).$$Where do I need the finite additivity?

Comment: I understood what you meant, but it is obvious that you haven't understood what I mean yet. I don't have time now, but will try to clarify later. For now, I am talking about continuity at a "point" (in this case, a particular subset), where you are only considering global continuity.